# Division Theorem. Well ordering principle required?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

Division Theorem: If $a$, $b$ are integers with $b > 0$, there exist integers $q$ and $r$ with $a = bq + r$ and $0 \leq r < b$.

Proof: Either $a$ is a multiple of $b$ ($a = bq$) or lies between multiples of $b$ ($bq < a < b(q+1)$). In the first case, (1) holds with $r = 0$. In the second case, $a-bq = r > 0$ and $a-bq = r < b$. Thus, $0 < r < b$. Together, $0 \leq r < b$.

Usually the proof of the existence of numbers $q$ and $r$ involves the well ordering principle and is somewhat longer. However, the above proof seems not to require it. Or is it presupposed in the first line of the proof?

Comment: Regardless of choice, there is a well-ordering on $\mathbb N$ (namely its "natural" ordering). So we don't need the well ordering principle to obtain such an order. In particular, this proof goes through without any form of choice.

Comment: For $a\geq 0$, you are using the well ordering of $\mathbb{N}$ to justify the existence of $q$: essentially, you are considering $t\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $bt\gt a$, and then letting $q+1$ be its least element.